# Scale/zoom UWP app automatically from HD to 4K

Tags: uwp, zooming, scaling, uwp-xaml, screen-resolution

Is there a way to replicate the HD layout of an application in a 4K screen (so that they look exactly the same), without having to manually calculate all font sizes, margins, paddings, etc. for the 4K screen and not having to set them in VisualState triggers?

Here's a sample of my current solution:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="ScreenWidthHDState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource ScreenWidthHD}" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SampleTextBlock.FontSize" Value="{StaticResource RegularFontSize}" />
                <Setter Target="SampleGrid.Margin" Value="6" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="ScreenWidth4KState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource ScreenWidth4K}"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SampleTextBlock.FontSize" Value="{StaticResource RegularFontSize4K}" />
                <!-- I'm multiplying the original value (6) by 1.33333 to achieve the exact same layout in 4K that I have in HD -->
                <!-- 4K resolution in effective pixels is 2560 wide (2560/1920 = 1.3333333...) -->
                <Setter Target="SampleGrid.Margin" Value="8" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

This works, but the issue is that what we have here is not really a responsive/adaptive design implementation, just a scaled/zoomed duplication of the HD layout to be shown in the 4K, so that you wouldn't notice a difference between both. The same effect could be achieved by changing the custom scaling of Windows in "Display Settings" to 200% with a resolution of 3840x2160, but this would require every client machine to be configured accordingly, which is not an option.

As you can imagine, manually calculating the dimensions of every single element in the app so that it looks exactly the same in HD and 4K is a tedious, time consuming and not scalable solution. I have tried to use ViewBox in a few different ways but the results are far from ideal, as I can't control how the layout will actually look after resizing the app window in different ways. Simply using a CompositeTransform with ScaleX/ScaleY values would make the app go out of bounds and force scrollbars, which is not acceptable as well.

Any solution for detecting screen resolution and magically scaling/zooming the app so that it looks exactly the same in HD and 4K?

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to **turn off scaling** when UWP app is **running on Xbox One**:

```cs
bool result = 
   Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewScaling.TrySetDisableLayoutScaling(true);
```

But I don't think there is any similar syntax to force scaling on desktop.

The scaling is **built-in to the OS** itself and the fact that the apps automatically take into account the scaling the user has set for the system is usually an advantage rather than disadvantage.

Said differently - if the app has small fonts, etc. on a 4K display set to 100%, then the problem will not be only in your app, but in all apps on that device and in such case the user is either consciously choosing this kind of display settings or she should consider changing them system wide, rather than for a specific app.